# Deploy web application with os image out of box

Tags: linux, deployment, web-hosting, vps

There is a web application which will be run on tomcat server on Linux x64 arcitecture.

Also I suppose, that potentially buyers who interested in this web application, will buy domain and hosting for it and install and configure necessary environment to it.

I have a centos7 image with installed and configured MySQL and tomcat. I can locally deploy my application.
But how can I create an out of box product which will be easily deployed on hosting?

Did you need to solve such problem? How did you do?
Is it possible to deploy to hosting Linux image with configure application?
Or I just can have an access to an empty os on server and have to install and configure environment MySQL and tomcat (e.g. run bash scripts) each time?

Comment: Yes, you can build an image and distribute that as a ready made package.  This is an easy way to scale up if need be. There are several orchestration tools you can use. Google is your friend.

Comment: Zavior, thank you for your answer. To be honest, I don't have such expirience, and really doesn't understand what my steps. Every hosting I see asked to select one of several proposal blank linux systems, but not for deploy my image. Do you know an example maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You can use turnkey solutions or plain scripts for installation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [Docker](https://www.docker.com/)? There is a [hub registry](https://hub.docker.com/) for uploading your packaged applications.

Deployment becomes very easy on any system capable or running Docker:

```
docker pull me/myapp
docker run -d -p 80:80 me/myapp
```

Alternatively there are hosting companies that specialize in containerized workloads.

- https://www.tutum.co/